# How to set up my network/bridging using Apple Airport equipment?

Tags: networking, bridge, airport

I'd like to set up my network like this, and I want to make sure it's possible using the hardware I have. I think it should be...

I've got my cable modem in one room. I want to plug it into an Apple Airport Express and create my wireless my wireless network here. The airport express will do the NAT and DHCP.

By my TV there are a few things to be networked (Xbox and Tivo). I have an airport extreme here. I'd like to have the airport extreme join the wireless network and share the connection to the ethernet ports.

Can anyone provide some assistance on the best way to configure to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the devices as a Wireless Distribution System (WDS). I've done this the other way around (using a Time Capsule as my WAN access point and an Airport Express as the extender). I don't have my hardware to hand, but you could try having a look at this [O'Reilly article](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/03/taming-an-airport-express-wds.html). If it's not any help reply here and I'll try to answer when I'm at home and near to my Airport gear.

Cheers,

Maurice